# Trying to Export From Photoshop to Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I am currently trying to export a few layers from Photoshop to Illustrator. However whenever I try and export, I get a blank ai document. I've also tried creating paths from my text (this is just text), and then exporting that to Illustrator. This works, however the paths that are generated in Photoshop aren't quite exact - that is, they don't quite match the text, clipping edges, and not using smooth lines.

I was able to export earlier in the week. To the best of my recollection, I just opened my document in Photoshop, and went to `File` ⇒ `Export Paths to Illustrator`, clicked OK a few times, and had my document in Illustrator. This doesn't seem to be working now.

What exactly could I be doing wrong? Is there anyway to make the paths created in Photoshop be more precise?

Comment: Also related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55345/how-to-keep-the-text-in-vector-in-photoshop-without-rasterizing-it-or-flattening

Answer (score 2):

When you export paths to Illustrator, the paths in Illustrator are non-filled, non-stroked paths. Therefore in Preview Mode you won't see anything.

Switch to Outline Modein Illustrator (View > Outline Mode) and you'll see the paths. You can then fill and stroke them so you can work on them in Preview mode.

Comment: I tried this, however nothing was in the document. I ended up having to open the PSD in ai - it then prompted me to convert it, and I was able to access the paths.

Answer (score 1):

It probably has to do with the vector paths of the layers you use. If yours are not a vector, you will be shown a blank document instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Save As > Photoshop EPS.

Make sure "Include Vector Data" box is checked in the resulting dialog prompt.

Open EPS in AI and the vectors from Photoshop should be there with fills intact.