# Problem with vectoring images from Photoshop to Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, pixelation

I am having problems vectoring art work for floor tiles. I vector the image in Photoshop then I save it as a Photoshop file and move it over to Illustrator. For these vector images the need to be able to be stretched or shrunk but still keep a straight line. not pixalated. What am I doing wrong?[image]

This is one of the images I have vectored in photoshop. Should I with to using AI?
When I have finished doing the image in Ai will it be able to be resized to any size and still keep a good strait line without pixelating?

Comment: You're using Photoshop. Why aren't you just using Illustrator? Are you exporting paths from Photoshop? (That's the only way to move actual vector path data to Illustrator).

Comment: I am tracing an image with photoshop and then I want to keep all my lines straight. I thought that was only possible by making it a smart object but its not keeping the properties of a smart object when I move it over to illustrator.

Comment: whats the best way to do this by scale?

Comment: I don't understand that question. What do you mean "by scale"?

Comment: So tried The method of tracing it but its not working.
these images need to be certain sizes and they need to be able to go big and keep the look of a fine line. And also to go small and keep the images fine line without pixelating at all. I thought the best way to do this was in photoshop.
It's pretty much like making a stencil that is used for different sizes. but still needs to have perfect straight lines and able to be resized....like a smart object.

Comment: Trace in Illustrator. There's no reason to use Photoshop if you ultimately want to end up in Illustrator.

Comment: I think you don't understand the inner workings of the programs. Paths are mathematical objects with no specific look to them. If they look jagged it is because you stroke them with the Pencil (no anti-aliasing) in Photoshop, rather than the Brush (with anti-aliasing). Illustrator artwork is anti-aliased by Default, so everything looks smooth. From what I see, you stroke paths with a Pencil, so that they look jagged or you disabled anti-aliased artwork in Illustrator. ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F9P9X.png)

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution would be to create the vectors in Illustrator to begin with but you could always try `Edit > Export > Paths to Illustrator` in Photoshop since importing the `.psd` file didn't work but check to see if it may be there in outline view by doing `View > Outline Mode` <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.

We have a similar question on this already here that may be useful:

["Trying to Export From Photoshop to Illustrator"](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5365/trying-to-export-from-photoshop-to-illustrator)

Answer (score 1):

**Here's the most straightforward method where you are right now.** 
Export from Photoshop as a high-resolution png. Import to Illustrator. Use the Image Trace tool to vectorize it. **BAM! Done!**