# How can I tell if my .psd file can be saved as a vector image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector

I have designed a logo for a client in Photoshop CS6 (I know, Illustrator, Illustrator) and all of the active layers consist either of Photoshop-generated shapes or editable text, aka nothing is a raster. While the .psd file does contain some rasterized layers, the only active ones are not. The company I must submit this logo to for printing only accepts full vector images in the file formats .pdf, .eps, and .ai. How can I save this file in such a way that I know that it maintains its vector qualities? Can I just save it as a PDF file as is?

Comment: What version of Photoshop are you using?

Comment: You can't. [**Click here**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/9462/3270) Photoshop **always** saves a raster file with embedded internal vector content. It is not possible to save a 100% vector file from Photoshop. If the printer is requesting a vector file, Photoshop is insufficient.

Comment: Also see here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17865/how-to-create-vector-graphics-in-photoshop-cs6/17873#17873

Comment: @Scott couldn't Dluks export the paths into Illustrator and re-do the strokes/fill/gradients seen here [Problem with vectoring images from Photoshop to Illustrator](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29064/problem-with-vectoring-images-from-photoshop-to-illustrator)? What do you think of this [Export your vector layers from PS to SVG](http://hackingui.com/design/export-photoshop-layer-to-svg/) plugin, however I haven't tested this out myself.

Comment: Yes, you can export *paths* to Illustrator then refill/restroke everything in Illustrator. But ultimately you can't save or export from Photoshop to get a complete, valid, 100% vector file. It's just a limitation of the app. And whether or not SVG works depends a **great deal** on how things are constructed in Photoshop. Anything remotely complex (gradients) will fall apart in the SVG export.

Comment: By "fall apart in SVG" I mean it'll include raster data. Some think it's just rhetoric that people post "Illustrator! Illustrator!" but there are very valid reasons for it.

Answer (score 0):

Open your .PSD with the layers in Illustrator.

Then choose "convert layers to object."

Not sure if it works with that version of Illustrator, and maybe you'll need to merge other layers together that can be rasterized... but it's worth trying. It works with the new Illustrator version though.

It might not work for the objects or maybe you'll need to isolate them on another Photoshop with layers and import them.

[Some details here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55345/how-to-keep-the-text-in-vector-in-photoshop-without-rasterizing-it-or-flattening)

Comment: This often results in vector containers with embedded raster images. Not great for logos and really, not much different than just saving the Photoshop file itself as a PDF or EPS. It's really just an extra step to get to the same (insufficient) result.

Comment: Indeed, it didn't do a real vector for objects when I tried it but it's great for text though :D I didn't try with paths but I guess it will create exactly what you described, and maybe only the "shape" can be salvaged. I'm already amazed the text can be imported, honestly!

Comment: Yeah.. you get the same results if you just "save as PDF" So there's not a great deal of benefit to this method. But it doesn't really make anything *worse* either.  It can be faster than exporting the *paths* from Photoshop though and kind of provide a template for refilling/restroking the vector containers - then you just delete all the embedded rasters.

Comment: I thought it would work too by simply exporting in PDF from Photoshop but in all my tests, the texts were not in vectors and it was always a rasterized image when opening them in Illustrator (and no I didn't compressed anything ha!) Opening the .psd was the only way I found that was making the text layers editable in Illustrator too.

Comment: Yup. Text seems to work better by opening the PSD, but nothing else is any better. If your'e dealing with a logo, where there may not be any actual live text, there's really no point to opening the PSD in Illustrator.